# Using Excel to plot a chart of change in ranking for two distinct groups

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm having a fight with Excel charts. Here's my scenario:

I have three columns of data: `Ranking1`, `Ranking2` and `Exp?` which are a number, a number and a boolean respectively. I want to create a line chart, of sorts, which shows each pair of rankings (rows containing a value from `Ranking1` and `Ranking2`) connected. I also want the boolean to be used to give each data entry one of two colours depending on the value of `Exp?`. I have attached a hand-drawn image below to illustrate this.

[image: Image of desired chart, as described above]

So far I have been able to plot all the data on a chart where each row is classified as single series. As you can see below, this is close but not quite what I want.

[image]

I am looking for a way to **compress** the data into a single series depending upon a boolean value, so that for the legend below, instead of ~60 series we only have two. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to change the colours of each series. Which, done manually would be a pain, but it can be done by selecting the chart and running this script:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count
    If Range("C" & i + 1) Then
        With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    Else
        With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

In should change the colours or each series based on the values in *Exp*

You can change `msoThemeColorAccent1` and `msoThemeColorAccent2` to whatever colours you want.

The script assumes *Exp* is in column `C`

Comment: Thanks this is useful, but I would still be left with over 60 distinct series in the legend. regardless, if no solution appears addressing this, I will accept this as an answer.